# Copy plaintext lines from file and append them to same file with mid-line prefix or remove mid-line prefix

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk

Making an ugly script that compiles a bunch of hosts files into one big list.

Most lists will have two entries for a URL, one with `www.` and one without like this:

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
```

However some of my lists don't double up like that, and I want them to. I have a lot of straggling URLs like this:

```
127.0.0.1 twitter.com
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 subdomain.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 tumblr.com
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com
```

What I'd like to do is scan the file for URLs that are listed to verify all lines without `www.` have a matching line with `www.`, and that all lines with a `www.` have a matching like without the `www.`. Then I want to append any missing lines to the list so my list would look like this:

```
127.0.0.1 twitter.com
127.0.0.1 www.twitter.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 subdomain.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.subdomain.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 tumblr.com
127.0.0.1 www.tumblr.com
127.0.0.1 reddit.com
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com
```

It doesn't need to be in order, I can just append all the missing lines on the end of the file because I run `sort -u` as a final step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just skip the checking and add the pair line anyway then pipe the output to `sort -u`:

```
sed '/ www./{                  # if line matches  www.
h                              # copy it over the hold buffer
s// /                          # remove the www. part
G                              # append the original line to the modified one
}
//!{                           # if line doesn't match  www.
h                              # copy it over the hold buffer
s/ / www./                     # add the www. part
G                              # append the original line to the modified one
}
' infile | sort -u
```

This assumes the two columns (IP and URL) are delimited by a space. Adjust the regex if needed.

---

Or, with `zsh`, you could read the lines in an array, remove the `www.` part where present and store the result in an array of unique elements then print each element twice, once as is and once with the `www.` part added:

```
mylist=(${(f)"$(<infile)"})
for i (${(u)mylist[@]/ www./ }) printf '%s\n' ${i} ${i/ / www.}
```

Comment: that's almost exactly the thought i had as well before reading this. vaguely I was considering: `sed -Ee's/[[:blank:]]+(www\.)?/ www./p;s// /' | sort -u`

Comment: @mikeserv -  yep; I like yours better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk` script:

**script.awk:**

```
{
    gsub("www.", "", $2)
    address[$2]
}
END{
    for (item in address){
        print("127.0.0.1", item)
        print("127.0.0.1", "www." item)
    }
}
```

Invoke it with

```
awk -f script.awk input
```

It removes `www.` at the beginning from all entries and then fills an array (with no value). If the value is already there, it will simply overwrite it, so you don't have to care about duplicates. In the end we print the content of the array, once as it is, and once with the `www.` prefix.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming I could change the two print commands to include "127.0.0.1 " and pipe them into a new file with >>? It looks like it's just printing it to the console without the localhost address as is.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the `127.0.0.1`. I edited my post. Yes, you can pipe the output to a file.